# is there a word to describe an instance of a person pretending to be lesser than what he/she actually is?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

Is there a word for someone who is a gifted artist pretending to be self-conscious about her work, to the point that she overindulges in self-pity and criticism, in an attempt to receive gratifying or reassuring comments?

> Despite the rave reviews, Barabara acted ____, and refused to accept the compliments.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is self-conscious, that's humility. If you think it's pretended, that's false humility. If it's to get compliments, that's "fishing for compliments".

Comment: yeah, i did think of “fishing for compliments”, but it seemed more like something people use colloquially. i was wondering if there was a more “formal” or “literal” word that one could use to epitomize the example i had

Comment: I could go with *self-effacing*, which is both formal and neutral; it gets harder to say succinctly when you add an element of disingenuousness.